# What's the best practise or elegant solution to handle lazy initialization in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In our project, we have an entity (just named it as 'X') which has some OneToMany associations with other entities e.g. let's say Set1, Set2, Set3 and Set4 etc. (fetch strategy are all 'Lazy'). We have a requirement that is based on different URL parameters we need to query 'X' and load different associated entities, for example, sometimes we need to get 'X' together with Set1 and Set2; Sometimes, we need to get 'X' together with Set2 and Set5; What associated entities should be loaded along with 'X' is defined by the URL parameter.

Of course, we can use JPA criteria API to dynamically query 'X' and join different associations based on the URL parameters to get right result but the problem is for the other associations which are not needed for the query of this time, the lazy initialization is easily triggered unexpectedly somewhere after we pass our entity 'X' back to upper layer. We may either get a lazy initialization exception from hibernate due to there is no open session in the context or get N+1 selecting performance issue. Are there some ways by which I can tell JPA or hibernate to stop lazy initialization after querying my entity 'X'? Because if so in this way I can safely pass 'X' to other layer without worrying to trigger lazy initialization.

Someone would say I should transfer 'X' into 'XDto' immediately after the query and pass 'XDto' to other layer but the problem is that how shall I know which associations should be converted and which ones should not in the logic of Dto converting? Because then I have to pass URL parameters to my Dto converting logic too in order to not touch the associations which are not loaded, it looks a bit ugly. I heard in JPA there is an API persistent util which can be used to check whether an association field is already initialized or not, before I try this, I'd like to ask are they any other elegant solutions which I can try? Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you ever considered writing stuff so that it is not in one unreadable block?  Try using paragraphs.

Comment: Hi! See [EntityGraph API](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph)

Comment: Instead of asking a question that cannot be answered here because it's way to broad you should use Google and you would find stuff like https://thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/

Comment: Hi Sergej, Simon, thanks very much for the reply but I'm not asking the ways to do lazy initialization, I know there are some proper ways to do that. However, what I want to ask or discuss is how to prevent lazy initialization by JPA after my query if the query dynamically defines which Sets should be loaded during the query.